# Popular form (Array de objetos)

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte array de objetos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que tenho deste objeto é o index, e quero utilizar este index para popular um formulário.

Na função abaixo, `fase` é o `array` e `ID` é o index do objeto.

Porem, da forma que está, eu só consigo popular o primeiro index[0].

Como posso fazer para exibir nos campos, as informações de acordo com o index correto ?

```
function _carrega_fase(fase, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fase.length; i++) {
        $('#txt_atraso_inicial_alt').val(fase[i].atraso_inicial);
        $('#txt_atraso_final_alt').val(fase[i].atraso_final);
        $('#txt_multa_alt').val(fase[i].multa);
        $('#txt_juros_alt').val(fase[i].juros);
        $('#txt_honorario_alt').val(fase[i].honorario);
    }
}
```

Eu espero que o formulario exiba as informações conforme abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de como o HTML é esperado ficar? Como está agora estás a sobre-escrever os mesmos elementos no HTML.

Comment: @Sergio, eu tenho um `Option Select`, que contem a faixa de atraso(Eu vou utilizar o `index` deste select para carregar as demais informações do objeto, e popular o `popover` com a `multa`, `juros` e `honorario`.

Comment: coloquei uma imagem em HTML de como espero que fique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do seu codigo, ele esta iterando por todos os elementos, e esta sobrescrevendo os valores dos campos a cada iteração, é essa mesmo a sua proposta?

Se o proposito for pegar um indice especifico e popular seu formulario experimente:

```
function _carrega_fase(fase, id) {
    $('#txt_atraso_inicial_alt').val(fase[id].atraso_inicial);
    $('#txt_atraso_final_alt').val(fase[id].atraso_final);
    $('#txt_multa_alt').val(fase[id].multa);
    $('#txt_juros_alt').val(fase[id].juros);
    $('#txt_honorario_alt').val(fase[id].honorario);
}
```

Comment: Isso funcionou, obrigado!!